# Refresh dynamic variable when used with Get

Tags: dynamic

I came across this issue with a more complicated program I was working on.

Suppose we have a volatile variable `data`:

```
In[1]:= data = RandomReal[{0,1},{10}];
```

As this cell is evaluated,

```
In[2]:= Dynamic@data
```

refreshes as expected.

However, if we want to save a certain instance of data and later load it in:

```
In[3]:= DumpSave["filepath.mx",data]
```

(change value of `data` to something else)

```
In[4]:= <<"filepath.mx"
```

the dynamic cell (`In[2]`) isn't updated (unless you evaluate it again). It can be forced to update on the loading of the .mx file by using a `Refresh[...,UpdateInterval->time]`, but it seems odd that re-evaluating `In[1]` instantly changes the dynamic cell while redefining `data` with the .mx file doesn't.

Any explanation for this? And is using the `Refresh` method a good solution here?

Comment: I always figured that `Update` was intended to be used exactly in situations like this, however it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have no insight into the internals but have found several situations where for whatever reasons the automatic determination of the necissity to update fails. I would wish there would be a programmatic possibility to tell Mathematica that a ceratin symbol has changed, but don't know about that. Of course you could do something stupid like this to inforce an update:

```
 Module[{datax = data}, data =.; data = datax]
```

Another workaround would be to use `Export` and `Import` instead of `DumpSave` and `Get`:

```
 Export["filepath.mx", data];
```

and then do:

```
 data = Import["filepath.mx"]
```

Here the explicit `Set` for data will trigger the update of the `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Often I do something kludgy like

```
Dynamic[foo; data]

<<"filepath.mx"; foo++
```

It's somewhat similar to Albert Retey's first solution.  However, `foo` is a global variable and `data` can be an arbitrary piece of code.

Here's a way to dress it up.  It does the same thing, but it reads better.

```
ClearAll[dependsOn, update];
SetAttributes[dependsOn, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[update, HoldAll];
dependsOn[sym_Symbol] := (
  dependsOn[sym] = 0;
  update[sym] := (dependsOn[sym] = 1 - dependsOn[sym];))

data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10}];
DumpSave["filepath.mx",data]

Dynamic[dependsOn[data]; data]

data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10}];

<< "filepath.mx"; update[data]
```